# How to combine an occurrence type of `VectorTop` with the vector's element type?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

This is a minimal example of the function that I can't get to typecheck:

```
(: int-sequence-to-vector ((Sequenceof Integer) -> (Vectorof Integer)))
(define (int-sequence-to-vector seq)
  (cond
    [(vector? seq) seq] ; This line is the problem.
    [else (for/vector : (Vectorof Integer) ([v seq]) v)]))
```

The goal is to preserve the type of the elements of the sequence (so, the function range should be `-> (Vectorof Integer)` rather than `-> Vectortop`) and to make operating on vectors a no-op.

The error is:

```
Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: (Vectorof Integer)
  given: (∩ (Sequenceof Integer) VectorTop) in: seq
```

I'm not sure what the difference is between `VectorTop` and `(Vectorof Any)`, and it also seems to me that a `(Sequenceof T)` that is also a `VectorTop` must be a `(Vectorof T)`.

The following adds a `cast` around the value:

```
(: int-sequence-to-vector ((Sequenceof Integer) -> (Vectorof Integer)))
(define (int-sequence-to-vector seq)
  (cond
    [(vector? seq) (cast seq (Vectorof Integer))]
    [else (for/vector : (Vectorof Integer) ([v seq]) v)]))
```

But that doesn't help:

```
Type Checker: Type (∩ (Sequenceof Integer) VectorTop) could not be 
converted to a contract: 
Intersection type contract contains more than 1 non-flat contract: 
(∩ (Sequenceof Integer) VectorTop) in: seq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem weird at first, but things are very different because vectors are mutable.

If something is a `(Sequenceof Integer)`, that only means that when you **get** an element from it it's an integer. But the type `(Vectorof Integer)` means that and something more. It means that when you **set** an element, you're allowed to set it to any integer you want.

```
(: mutate-vector-of-integer : (Vectorof Integer) -> Void)
(define (mutate-vector-of-integer voi)
  (vector-set! voi 0 -987654321))      ; can set it to any integer
```

Because of this, typechecking with vectors has to be stricter than with sequences.

For example, with sequences you can pass a `(Sequenceof Byte)` to a function expecting a `(Sequenceof Integer)` and it's no problem. Even passing a `(Vectorof Byte)` to a function expecting a `(Sequenceof Integer)` is fine, but only because `Sequenceof` by itself doesn't allow you to mutate the sequence.

However, using a `(Vectorof Byte)` as a `(Vectorof Integer)` can't be allowed because of the possibility of mutation. The technical term for this is that `Vectorof` is *invariant*.

```
(define vob : (Vectorof Byte)
  (vector 1 2 3))
(expect-vector-of-integer vob)
;Type Checker: type mismatch
;  expected: (Vectorof Integer)
;  given: (Vectorof Byte) in: vob
```

This is also why `VectorTop` is different from `(Vectorof Any)`. The type `(Vectorof Any)` tells you two things: when you get an element it has type `Any`, and that when you set an element you're allowed to use `Any`. In contrast, the type `VectorTop` doesn't give you any of the "set" information, so `VectorTop` by itself doesn't allow mutation.

Comment: First of all, thanks!  I thought about mutability, but mistakenly ruled it out when I saw that `vector-immutable` returns `Vector` types that can't be mutated.  After reading your answer, I experimented more and saw that `vector-set!` on an immutable `(Vectorof Integer)` is prohibited by a *contract*, not by the type itself, whereas mutating a  `(∩ (Sequenceof Integer) VectorTop)` is a type error, for the reasons you explained.     

Is there a way to work around this and have values of type `(Vectorof Integer)` pass through the example function while retaining their type?

Comment: They are working on types for immutable vectors in TR. Otherwise, maybe the best strategy is to copy the vector. Like what you already do in your else case, but you can do vector-specific things like allocating the right length to begin with.